# How to collapse/expand Eclipse resources tree (Project Explorer) in Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse and I been trying without success to figure out how to collapse or expand workspace's resource tree.

For example, to refresh my whole workspace I wrote the code:

```
   for(IProject project : ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getProjects()){
        try {
            project.refreshLocal(IResource.DEPTH_INFINITE, new NullProgressMonitor());
        } catch (CoreException e) {}
    }
```

But After it I want to expand the whole tree and I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: If you mean to collapse or expand the tree in one of the existing views, why? Tampering with another view's presentation is usually a bad thing.

Comment: There is no official API for doing this. In any case what if the user is using Package Explorer or the old Resource Navigator?

Comment: The real reason why I wanted to do it is that I realized that creating markers for resources, when tree is expanded, is very time consuming! That is, using this code: org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.MarkerUtilities.createMarker(...) when all tree is collapsed, takes much much less time comparing to expanded tree.